# using for loop value from javascript with php variable

Tags: php, javascript

I have this code that executes a for loop in javascript with a php array inside of it.  Is there anyway I can use the variable for the loop inside of the php variable for example.  This is all inside of php.

```
echo '<script>
for (var i =0; i<4;i++){

alert("hey"'.$phparr[i].');



}</script>';
```

I know this will not work because the $phparr is a php variable while the i is a javascript variable is there anyway I can do this?

Comment: There are a lot of downvotes on answers in this question. Is someone taking them personally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<script>    
    var phparr = <?php echo json_encode($phparr); ?>;

    for (i in phparr){

        alert("hey" + phparr[i]);

    }
</script>
```

PHP is a [server side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) which means it executes before it reaches the client (browser).

JavaScript is a [client side language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) which means it is executed in the browser (client side).

The best tool for a new web developer is Google search.
[Learn how to search effectively.](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=134479)

Comment: I used `for (i in phparr)` because I have no idea what your keys are and how many there are.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. In order to access the php array in javascript, you first have to echo out the php array into a javascript array. Try:

```
$phparr_imploded = implode(',',$phparr);
echo '
    <script>
        var arr = ['.$phparr_imploded.'];
        for (var i =0; i<4;i++){
            alert("hey"+arr[i]);
        }
    </script>
';
```

If your php array is coming from a database, or contains special characters that javascript may misinterpret, make sure to sanitize before outputting.

Are the objects in your php array strings? If so, you need to surround the objects with escaped quotations BEFORE the implode.

```
for($i=0; i<count($phparr); $i++){
    $phparr[i] = '"'.$phparr[i].'"';
};
```

Comment: Hey this worked great however the strings contained in my array are actually html.  I have for example an array of <option value = 'someting'>something</option>.  Right now it is just something with out the quotes because otherwise javascript will not take it.  Is there anyway to be able to have those in there otherwise I can't print my options inside of my javscript select.

Comment: Ah, well remember there are 2 types of quotes, single and double quotes. When working with 3 different languages at once (html, javascript, and php) it can get tricky.

Based on the code you put earlier, the alerts should work. I assume that its not the code you're struggling with at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

How about storing the PHP array in a Javascript variable and looping through as kpotehin suggests?

```
<script>
var i = 0, name;
var myArr = <?php echo json_encode($my_array); ?>;

while (name = myArr[i++]){
  alert("hey " + name);
}
</script>
```

Comment: (this assumes that `$my_array` holds the array in PHP)

Answer (score -1):

You should make it this way:

```
var arr = ["<?php echo implode('","',$array); ?>"];
for (var i =0; i<4;i++){
alert("hey"+ arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Using json_encode is typically better than doing something like that.  The reason why is that what if one of your $array elements contains a quote?

Answer (score -1):

Your basic problem is that you are forgetting that the PHP code and the JavaScript code *do not execute at the same time*. The PHP runs to completion, outputing HTML and JavaScript. Then the browser runs the JavaScript. If the JavaScript needs dynamic access to data in a PHP variable (including an array), then the PHP needs to generate JavaScript declaring the data in a JavaScript structure. That is what all the other answers are doing.